# Inequality in $3$ variables with constraint

Tags: inequality

How can I prove that if 
$$
(x+y+z-3)^2=xy+yz+zx-3, \ x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}
$$
Then 
$$
3+ xyz(x+y+z)\geq 6xyz
$$ 
without using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: are these positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, the condition does not depend on $w^3$ and we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$, where $f$ is a linear function.

But a linear function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Id est, it remains to prove our inequality for $y=x$ and $(2x+z-3)^2=x^2+2xz-3$.

We need to prove that $3+x^2z(2x+z)\geq6x^2z$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: In this case $v^2\ge 1$ from the condition, so that isn't a complication. However proving extrema of $w^3$ occurs when two among the variables are equal may need Lagrange or a more complicated theorem than the question itself.

Comment: @ Macavity $x$, $y$ and $z$ are real roots of the equation $X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X=w^3$. Draw graph of $f(X)=X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X$ and a line $Y=w^3$ and you'll see that it's obvious (about occurring of extremal value of $w^3$).

Comment: I am aware of the $u, v, w$ method and its proof (without resorting to visualizing multidimensional graphs) - I don't think its as trivial as you make it though.  There must be simpler solutions.

Comment: @Macavity draw a cube parabola and a parallel line to OX and I am sure that you'll see that it's trivial. It's indeed trivial.